# How to get a value with 2 decimals with toLocalString?

Tags: javascript

I want a number to be displayed as decimal with two digits behind the comma. In Addition the number need to be formated as local string. How can I achieve that?

```
  var initialValue = 3000; // shall be displayed as 3,000.00 or 3.000,00
  initialValue.toLocalString();  //digits are missing
  initialValue.toFixed(2);  // local format is missing
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `options` parameter of [`Number#toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString), with

```
minimumFractionDigits: 2
useGrouping: true
```

for two digits and grouping separator.

```js
var initialValue = 3000,
    stringValue = initialValue.toLocaleString(undefined, { minimumFractionDigits: 2, useGrouping: true });

console.log(stringValue);
```

Comment: ...then just set `useGrouping` to true.